# WebApplicationInitializer container.addServlet() returns null

Tags: eclipse, web-applications, spring-data

I am creating a basic web app with maven, then importing to Eclipse 4.2.  I have Tomcat 7 setup as a server.  I am trying to configure spring data with mongodb for a web app.

I am following the code-based configuration approach found here: [WebApplicationInitializer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html)

When I run the project on the server, I get a null pointer exception in the WebApplicationInitializer class I have created.  The line: 
container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext)); is returning null.

What the heck am I missing?  I am a bit new to creating web-apps from scratch using annotations.

Here is the class in question:

```
public class ATWWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer
{
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException  
    {
      // Create the 'root' Spring application context
      AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new  AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
      rootContext.register(SpringMongoConfig.class);

      // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
      container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

      // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
      AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
      dispatcherContext.register(ATWDispatcherConfig.class);

      // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
      ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
      dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
      dispatcher.addMapping("/*");
    }
}
```

Tried adding this to the POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Didn't change anything, still getting the NPE.  I read here (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) that container.addServlet returns null if a servlet is already registered?  Is Tomcat registering a servlet already?

Apologies for wasting everyone's time, **I had a web.xml file also registering the same servlet.**  So this one was only returning null.  Now on to fixing the 404, probably screwed up the controller somehow.

Comment: Not really sure, a similar setup works cleanly for me. So essentially you are getting a null pointer exception on `dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup()` line right, considering that the previous line is giving a null dispatcher?

Comment: That is correct.  The next line accessing the dispatcher is throwing the NPE.  I'm thinking it might have something to do with the servlet-api.  I didn't set up a dependency in the POM, I only added the jar to my build path from the tomcat lib directory.

Comment: Hmmmm, I am having exactly the same problem and I do not have any `web.xml` file, trying to do it pure annotated.

Comment: I was getting this and fixed it by  backing out my org.mockito / mockito-all dependency.

Comment: You should post your "Apologies" section as the answer." I had the same issue and this post helped.

Answer (score 13):

According to ServletContext [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) the method addServlet() will return null if a servlet with the specified name is already registered.

Comment: Thank you. I was pulling out my hair over this. Yours was the only answer in the entire internet space and it turned out to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

@Ravi Rao - You are precisely correct. I was struggling hard to run my app on the tomcat and was getting the NPE exactly at dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup().

But when I read the answer you provided, I realized that there was another application running on the same tomcat with the same name of that dispatcher servlet.

I just renamed my dispatcher servlet and it worked amazingly.
Just mentioned the exact steps to resolve this issue. In case someone find it useful